# Angular 2: function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing

I have a bunch of modules which have their routes setup at run time, based on the content of a JSON file (which means I **have** to use a function here unless I want to break my previous logic). I have a function that parses the data into a `Routes` object and then returns it:

```
export function getRoutes(): Routes {
    let routes: Routes = [
        //default component
        {
            path: '',
            component: AComponent
        }
    ];

    for(let module of APP_CONFIG.modules){
        routes.push({
            path: module.path,
            loadChildren: module.modulePath
        })
    }
    return routes;
}
```

And then I simply call the function in my `module`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //[...]
  ],
  imports: [
    //[...]
    RouterModule.forRoot(getRoutes())
  ],
  providers: [
    //[...]
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However, my project (which was generated by angular-cli) won't build:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'getRoutes', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function
```

I followed the instructions in the error message, and it built **once**. Then it continued to fail over and over again with the same message.

So I guess my question is: How the hell do I fix this stupid problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I'm still searching... :(

Answer (score 0):

> Direct use of function in route is not supported by AoT. Either avoid using it or export it from other module.

Don't:

```
function random() {
  return [{
    path: "",
    component: AppViewComponent
  }];
}
const SAMPLE_APP_ROUTES: Routes = random();
```

Do:

```
const SAMPLE_APP_ROUTES: Routes = [{
  path: "",
  component: AppViewComponent
}];
```

or

```
import { random } from "./random.routes.ts";
const SAMPLE_APP_ROUTES: Routes = random();
```

Source: https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#func-in-routes-top

Comment: I tried this; it's what I meant when I said that I 'followed the instructions in the error message'. It built **once**.